# How to Deny all IPs except one in Filezilla Server?

Tags: ip, ftp

Using the standard Filezilla IP Filter GUI interface seen here, I want to deny *all* IP addresses in the first box and in the second box allow only one IP# back in.

Am having problems with CIDR notation in the first box to capture all IPs. Looking for help with that, unless there is a better way.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Wildcards are supported**. I just successfully used:

Not allowed IPs:

> *

followed by ...

Enable (allow):

> 192.168.100.139

Well, that was easy.

Comment: You cheated by pushing the Easy Button.

Comment: @Kalamane, that's true but I'd accept other solutions too. The more the merrier. By wildcard is the first way I found, but would like to also see a more IP-based approach.

Comment: This is so counterintuitive. The UI says it accepts CIDR but 0.0.0.0/0 get rejected...

Comment: What about multiple enabled IP addresses? Spaces aren't working for me.

Comment: Multiple allowed IP addresses (or ranges in CIDR notation) should go separate lines. Considering that almost half of the dialog windows is dedicated to explanations, it still leaves many open questions...

Answer (score 0):

I found * for block all and allowed IP's on separate lines to be accepted by Filezilla